# Error in ADF with my custom methods

Tags: java, oracle, nullpointerexception, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 12c. In my web application I am supposed to implement button "Set active" which changes value of checkbox "active" from 0 to 1. Also I cannot have more than one year active, so I wrote a two methods to criteria this year and second one to set attribute value 1.

Codes are here:

```
public void getDeesconfView() {
    DeesconfView vo = getDeesconfView;
    ViewCriteriaManager vcm = vo.getViewCriteriaManager();
    ViewCriteria vc = vcm.getViewCriteria("Active");
    VariableValueManager vvm = vc.ensureVariableManager();
    vvm.setVariableValue("Active", 0);
    vo.applyViewCriteria(vc);
    vo.executeQuery();
}

public void activeYear() {
     getDeesconfView(); 
    this.getCurrentRow().setAttribute("Aktywny", 1);
}
```

> ```
>  Code for my active button:
>  <af:button text="Set active" id="b1" actionListener="#{bindings.activeYear.execute}"
>                   disabled="#{!bindings.activeYear.enabled}"
> ```

And error code:

```
<2014-04-22 08:21:06 CEST> <Error> <javax.faces.event> <BEA-000000>        <javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: ADFv: Exception "interrupt processing".
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlActionBinding.execute(FacesCtrlAction   Binding.java:202)
at    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlActionBinding.execute(FacesCtrlActionBinding.java:202)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.broadcast(UIXComponentBase.java:986)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:179)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.broadcast(UIXRegion.java:123)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:107)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:130)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:461)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:134)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:101)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1083)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:402)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:225)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:192)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:106)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:478)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:478)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:303)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:208)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:202)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:225)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

I don't see any errors in my code, but in my application I have nullPointerException:

after I press button "Set active".

Have somebody any ideas, what could go wrong in this code?

Regards,

WK

Comment: Please, provide us the stack trace of the error, and the code snippet of the button on your web page.

Comment: Where have you written these methods?